How to connect to SharePoint Server 2019 API (on-premise) without ADFS?
I'm running a SharePoint 2019 Server on-premise and want to connect via API or CSOM by using C#
Most samples out there just show how to authenticate against SharePoint Online by using Graph API or Azure AD / Entra ID. I don't have an ADFS server available to use STS.
Is there any alternative to authenticate, e.g. using client id and client secret? The App-Only approach also seems to require an ADFS, right? At least all samples I have seen also use https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please refer this article: Granting access using SharePoint App-Only.
In this way, we can connect to SharePoint using client id and client secret.

